# Visual Studio Publish/Deployment using File System with Power Shell Script

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-publish

I have a Visual Studio 2019 project that I want to locally deploy to a network folder.
\\api\c$\inetpub\wwwroot  The path requires a user name and password.  Which The default visual studio publish does not prompt I simply get this error.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression
>   State Suppression State Error     Unable to create directory
>   "\\api\c$\inetpub\wwwroot\API\v1\". The user name or
>   password is incorrect. API.Web.NET        0

- What I am thinking is a power shell script that I could include in the project.
- I could publish locally then copy to the network.
- I want the user name and password to prompt so nothing is hard coded.

Any ideas or links would help

Answer (score 0):

You can use Get-Credential to prompt for both username and password.

```
$credential = Get-Credential
Copy-Item $yourlocalpublishpath $yourdestinationpath -Credential $credential
```